# Set hbase paramter for spark job

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hbase

Is there a way to pass hbase.rpc.timeout to a spark job , which is called through a shell script. I know we can set the hbase.rpc.timeout value when creating the HBaseConfiguration in the spark job it self. But I want to pass the value from shell .

Something like :

```
 ${SPARK_SUBMIT} 
    --class mySpark \
    --num-executors ${NUM_EXECUTORS} \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --hbase.rpc.timeout 600000 . \
    ${SPARK_JAR} "${START_TIME}" "${END_TIME}" "${OUTPUT_PATH}" 2>&1 | tee -a ${logPath}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two methods

1. regrad `hbase.rpc.timeout 600000` as the application arguments. And process it in your `SPARK_JAR`
2. like what you want `--conf hbase.rpc.timeout=600000`. Then `sparkContext.getConf().get("hbase.rpc.timeout")`